# How to count 2 records with similar ID in 2 columns as one?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have records which are "Tasks" by system definition (Project Server).
For each task row there are multiple columns being used, and some tasks might have different dates and other information, but I want to count or merge records that have the same data in 2 columns:  `"Tool ID"` and `"Activity type"`

For example:

```
Task Index      Finish Date     Activity type      Tool ID      ...

741             3/20/2016       T1                 100123
742             3/28/2016       Delay T1           100123
743             4/2/2016        T1                 100123
744             4/10/2016       T2                 100123
...
...
```

I want to have the 2 records with similar Tool ID and Activity type (Index: 741,743) to be counted as 1.

Ignore the date, index and other columns I need on the output, but have a field or something else for my report that will count the combination of "100123" and "T1" as 1.

Tried distinct, group by, and a few other techniques, but it didn't work.

Comment: "Ignore the date ... I need on the output" - if you're combining two records, which date you need to see in output?

Comment: Could you put an example with the result that you want?

Comment: This sounds like a perfect example of a scenario that calls for a `group by`, so what do you mean when you say that it "didn't work"? Can you share the query you tried and the problem you're seeing?

Comment: Hi, i have shared the query later in this post.

Comment: the date i need to have in the report output is:

Tool ID    Activity          Count T1  Count delay T1


100123     T1                2                 0
100123     Delay T1      0                 1   
100123     T2                0                 0

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could concatenate the two fields and count them distinct:

```
count(distinct (tool_id||activity_type))
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a CTE to perform the counting, and then combine that with the original data.

```
WITH CTE1 AS (
    SELECT [Tool ID], [Activity type], COUNT(*) [MyCount] 
    FROM @MyTable
    GROUP BY [Tool ID], [Activity type]
    )
SELECT A.*, C.MyCount 
FROM @MyTable A INNER JOIN CTE1 C
    ON  A.[Activity type] = C.[Activity type] AND 
        A.[Tool ID] = C.[Tool ID]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try following query

```
DECLARE @Tbl TABLE ([Task Index] INT, [Finish Date] DATETIME, [Activity type] NVARCHAR(50), [Tool ID] INT)

INSERT INTO @Tbl VALUES (741, N'3/20/2016', 'T1', 100123)
INSERT INTO @Tbl VALUES (742, N'3/28/2016', 'Delay T1', 100123)
INSERT INTO @Tbl VALUES (743, N'4/2/2016',  'T1', 100123)
INSERT INTO @Tbl VALUES (744, N'4/10/2016', 'T2', 100123)

SELECT
    COUNT(*) AS YourCount -- Output 3
FROM
(
    SELECT DISTINCT     
        T.[Activity type],
        T.[Tool ID]     
    FROM
        @Tbl T
) A
```